# What is the wrong with this sign in command? (Error: Store IsDiskFile() failed)

Tags: sign, signtool

I want to sign in a single dll using this command.

```
signtool sign /f $qD:\DIN\DIN_DMCC_Microsoft_PrivateKey.pfx$q /p $qD*****N DM(($q $f d:\agsXMPP.dll))
```

When i run that it says
[image]

SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
Error information: "Error: Store IsDiskFile() failed." (-2147024773/0x8007007b)

How to overcome this?

Comment: I had this when the path of the private key was wrong, I don't know why it didn't reply with the standard error message